# Care and feeding of my mature redwoods on my property in Northern California (25 miles from the coast)

Tags: trees

My mature redwoods look very stressed right now. I do not have any irrigation system. I have to use a hose.  How often should I water them?  How much should I water each time?  Does adding mulch near the base help?

Best Regards,

Tim Shaw

Comment: Pictures please!

Comment: "Mature" is a bit vague, too - redwood trees can live over a thousand years.

Answer (score 2):

Tim, I had the same issue in Walnut Creek. Our 80’ redwood was looking scraggly. Called a arborist to check it out and he said just put a lawn sprinkler at the base and leave it run a half hour each week or every two weeks. I did it more frequently at first and got a nice bloom of new growth. Now the rains should sustain it, if they return. As for mulch, arborists have told me in the past it’s best to let the redwood debris mulch itself.